# Python httplib2.Http not sending post parameters

Tags: python

I have been trying to make an API request to Twilio using the httplib2 Http class and no matter how I try to setup the request, it doesn't send my post DATA. I know this, because I posted to a local URL and the post arguments are empty. Here is my code:

```
_TWILIO_URL = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%s/%s'
class Api(object):
    '''
    A Python interface to the Twilio API
    '''

    def __init__(self, AccountSid, AuthToken, From):
        self.AccountSid = AccountSid
        self.AuthToken = AuthToken
        self.From = From

    def _get_from(self, From):
        """Use the provided From number or the one defined on initialization"""
        if From:
            return From
        else:
            return self.From

    def call(self, To, Url, From=None):
        """Sends a request to Twilio having it call a number; the provided URL will indicate how to handle the call"""
        url = _TWILIO_URL % (self.AccountSid, 'Calls')
        data = dict(From=self._get_from(From), To=To, Url=Url)
        return self.request(url, body=urlencode(data))

    def request(self, url, method='POST', body=None, headers={'content-type':'text/plain'}):
        """Send the actual request"""
        h = Http()
        h.add_credentials(self.AccountSid, self.AuthToken)
        resp, content =  h.request(url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers)

        print content

        if resp['status'] == '200':
            return loads(content)
        else:
            raise TwilioError(resp['status'], content)

    def sms(self, To, Body, From=None):
        """Sends a request to Twilio having it call a number; the provided URL will indicate how to handle the call"""
        url = _TWILIO_URL % (self.AccountSid, 'SMS/Messages')
        data = dict(From=self._get_from(From), To=To, Body=Body)
        return self.request(url, body=urlencode(data))
```

I can't find anything on google talking about troubleshooting

Answer (score 3):

Twilio mentions this requirement in [their API docs concerning POST requests](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request#post):

> But be sure to set the HTTP
>   Content-Type header to
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   for your requests if     you are
>   writing your own client.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the 'content-type' has to be set to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. If anyone knows why, please let me know.

Comment: Because that is what the content-type IS. Although it may be the most obvious content-type for POST requests (when used from html forms), POST can be used for other content like html, xml, pdf etc... as well, and even html forms are not limited to just this type (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4). Look at it this way: you are posting a "file", and you have to declare what type it is.